# Назвать файл переменной

Tags: c

Как мне в си назвать файл тем, что записано в переменной?

Comment: Покажите ваш код, как вы попытались это сделать.

Comment: new_file = fopen(login + ".txt", "r+a");

Comment: char login[100];

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> char login[100];
> new_file = fopen(login + ".txt", "r+a");
> ```

В C нельзя соединять строки с помощью оператора `+`.

Можно изменить `login` и дописать в конец `".txt"`, вот так:

```
strcat(login, ".txt");
```

И тогда можно сделать просто `fopen(login, ...)`.

---

Домашнее задание: выяснить, на что заменить `strcat`, чтобы не было риска вылезти за границу массива.

Comment: А как файл назвать то переменной?

Comment: `fopen(login, ...)`.

Comment: Ой блин. Я вижу что пишет ошибка сегментирования и думаю что надо как то по другому писать, а потом вспомнил что fopen не создаёт файлы.

Comment: @RoyaleXPlay Как это не создает? От режима зависит, если поставить `w` вместо `r`, то должен создать.

Comment: Именно у мене не создаёт. А так надо ставить параметр со знаком +.

Comment: Если вы **создаете** файл, то создавайте правильно. Если вы хотите, чтобы файл создавался, если его еще нет - нужно использовать `w`, `a`, `w+` или `a+`, но не странное `r+a` - см. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen